# i can't run c++ on vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, msys

So, i have followed this [guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) and watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMWD7wfhgNY) i even check that (gcc,g++,gdb) --version command works but i still have an issue once i try to run my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

the issue:

```
Starting build...
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g C:\Users\matLe\Documents\martin\programmation\premier_dossier\programme.cpp -o C:\Users\matLe\Documents\martin\programmation\premier_dossier\programme.exe
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\matLe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGOz3M3.o: in function `main':
C:/Users/matLe/Documents/martin/programmation/premier_dossier/programme.cpp:4:(.text+0x22): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/matLe/Documents/martin/programmation/premier_dossier/programme.cpp:4:(.text+0x34): undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ostream& (*)(std::ostream&))'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\matLe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGOz3M3.o:programme.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_[.refptr._ZSt4endlIcSt11char_traitsIcEERSt13basic_ostreamIT_T0_ES6_]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::endl<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&)'
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\matLe\AppData\Local\Temp\ccGOz3M3.o:programme.cpp:(.rdata$.refptr._ZSt4cout[.refptr._ZSt4cout]+0x0): undefined reference to `std::cout'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my task.json file content:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "type": "cppbuild",
            "label": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file",
            "command": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
            "args": [
                "-fdiagnostics-color=always",
                "-g",
                "${file}",
                "-o",
                "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
            ],
            "options": {
                "cwd": "C:\\msys64\\ucrt64\\bin"
            },
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$gcc"
            ],
            "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "detail": "Task generated by Debugger."
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You're missing the C++ runtime library.  Use `.../bin/g++.exe` instead of gcc.exe.

Comment: GCC is smart enough to _compile_ C++ code using the C++ backend, but then tries to _link_ it as C. Hence why your error stems from `ld.exe` rather than the compiler.

Comment: Lot of this going around lately and I don't know why. I thought perhaps Microsoft changed the insturctions to something more generic, but no. The [linked documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_understanding-tasksjson) is quite explicit that you must use g++.

Comment: I blame the notion people have that "native" development is always easier. I do my C++ stuff through WSL when I'm on Windows. It's so much simpler, a large part thanks to the offical WSL support. But I also flip flop between VS Code and a modal CLI editor, so meh.

Comment: Side note: The recommendation that you add the bin folder to the path gets you going quickly, but it also sets you up for [DLL Hell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DLL_Hell). A lot of tools use the mingw DLLs and if you have two tools in the path using different versions of the mingw DLLs (or any DLLs for that matter), you're in for some hard-to-troubleshoot mystery errors.